# How to check if a LineString intersects a LineString (or Polygon)

Tags: java, mapbox, geojson

I am using the MapBox SDK. I have ran into an issue. I am trying to create a path that avoids certain areas, which are denoted as Polygons on the map. I want to check if my LineString will intersect a Polygon. I have seen there is a method outer() which gives me the perimeter of the Polygon as a LineString, however I am not sure how to proceed.

I need to find a way to give me a boolean whether or not my LineString path will intersect the perimeter, meaning I will be able to find an alternative route.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this [line-line intersection algorithm](https://www.topcoder.com/thrive/articles/Geometry%20Concepts%20part%202:%20%20Line%20Intersection%20and%20its%20Applications#LineLineIntersection) in a function. At the end of the paragraph you will also find a way to check if a line intersects a segment line.

Using the [`outer()`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/api/libjava-geojson/5.8.0/com/mapbox/geojson/Polygon.html#outer--) method and the line-line interscection function, you can check if your `LineString` intersects any line segment of your `Polygon`.

I'm thinking of such signatures, but you could do it differently :

```
public boolean lineIntersectsLine(LineString line1, LineString line2){
    //line-line intersection algorithm
};

public boolean lineIntersectsSegment(LineString line, LineString segment){
    //line-line intersection algorithm + check if intersection point is on segment
};

public boolean lineIntersectsPolygon(LineString line, Polygon polygon){
    //lineIntersectSegment for each segment of polygon
};
```

Other links that could help you : [equation of a Line from 2 Points](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-2points.html), [check if two given line segments intersect](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/)